# High demand on Azure Cosmos DB Emulator when adding a new collection

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

When I'm trying to add a new collection to database I'm getting this error :

```
Failed to create collection 'Products'.

Error:
Sorry, we are currently experiencing high demand in this region, and cannot 
fulfill your request at this time. We work continuously to bring more and 
more capacity online, and encourage you to try again. Please do not hesitate 
to email docdbswat@microsoft.com at any time or for any reason.
ActivityId: bad1a40a-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, 
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.22.0.0
```

It's a local emulator, what kind of high demmand in this region ?

Comment: This is [documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator), if you exceed the maximum number of partitions configured for the emulator.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#set-partitioncount).

> By default, you can create up to 25 single partition collections, or 1 partitioned collection using the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator. By modifying the PartitionCount value, you can create up to 250 single partition collections or 10 partitioned collections, or any combination of the two that does not exceed 250 single partitions (where one partitioned collection = 25 single partition collection).

So basically, if you want to create more partitioned collections or more single-partition collections, just increase the `PartitionCount` when starting from the command-line:

```
CosmosDB.Emulator.exe /PartitionCount=100
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Why is the limitation there ? 
Isn't this supposed to work on a developer machine ... which we already have lots of collections to test and drop in a lots of projects

Comment: Actually, it did work after cleanup and re-installation. I tried 250, but the computer became slow and takes time to boot the emulator. So I went back to the default.

Comment: It will consume more environment resources, because it needs to allocate more space and resources for those partitions, that's why the default is not 250.

Comment: I can't understand why it should allocate space and resources ahead of time. I thought it was just a "limitation" number. 
Anyway, I believe Microsoft should reconsider this

Comment: How does one change this setting when running the emulator in Docker?

Comment: @ShawndeWet did you find out?

Comment: @sharpc nothing.  I never did figure this out.

Comment: @ShawndeWet you can use an env var (AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT) and set it to an higher amount. The higher, the slower the container will start.

Answer (score 5):

Someone else on my team could get this working without the need for `CosmosDB.Emulator.exe /PartitionCount=100`. We could see that the containers where not being created.

Microsoft explains how to resolve this issue:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#set-partitioncount

[image]

[image]

1. Reset Data
2. Exit CosmosDb
3. Go to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\CosmosDBEmulator` and delete all content
4. Restart your machine for good measure

You should now be able to retry and all should work.

Comment: Thanks! @Sigex, I followed the same steps and it worked for me.

Comment: But this step worked only for first time after restarting. Post that getting same error. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

The CosmosDB emulator has some limitations and this is the generic message that it will throw if you exceed those limitations.

The reason you got that is because you tried to make more than 10 collections in a database, but there are other reasons you might get the same error as well.

You can read more about the [differences between the Emulator and the service here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#differences-between-the-emulator-and-the-service).