# How to pass multiple parameters when starting Azure Cosmos DB Emulator?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I wanted to test out the Patch API, I followed the docs on the [github](https://github.com/AzureCosmosDB/PatchPrivatePreviewFeedbackGroup) to test Patch API with Emulator,

```
C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator> .\CosmosDB.Emulator.exe /EnablePreview
```

which works fine, however when i start inserting items it throws an error,

> Sorry, we are currently experiencing high demand in this region, and
> cannot  fulfill your request at this time.

I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614989/high-demand-on-azure-cosmos-db-emulator-when-adding-a-new-collection/51617916), how can i run this command and the above command together when starting the emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you simply need to run ,

```
.\CosmosDB.Emulator.exe /EnablePreview /PartitionCount=100
```

in the Cosmos Emulator Folder

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan! Much appreciated :)